# List all possible paths using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I would like to list all paths of object that lead to leafs

Example:

```
var obj = {
 a:"1",
 b:{
  foo:"2",
  bar:3
 },
 c:[0,1]
}
```

Result:

```
"a","b.foo","b.bar", "c[0]","c[1]"
```

I would like to find simple and readable solution, best using lodash.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh The only solution that comes to my head is simple recursion that travels through the object.

Comment: yes.. thats what you can do.. what have u tried so far? can you share some code and exact problem you are facing?

Comment: Maybe this should be a lodash feature request. Given that lodash provides _.get, _.set, _.unset, and _.has with arbitrary paths (with arrays or dot-delimited strings), which are great ways of dealing with nested objects, some extra utilities for listing paths, finding differences, and (this is really bugging me) _.merge()ing with some possibility of deleting vals (`_.merge({a:1},{a:undefined})  // actual: {a:1},  desired: {}`) would be nice.

Comment: You can use [flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat) package for this.
Example: `Object.keys(flat(/* obj */))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses lodash in as many ways as I can think of:

```js
function paths(obj, parentKey) {
  var result;
  if (_.isArray(obj)) {
    var idx = 0;
    result = _.flatMap(obj, function (obj) {
      return paths(obj, (parentKey || '') + '[' + idx++ + ']');
    });
  }
  else if (_.isPlainObject(obj)) {
    result = _.flatMap(_.keys(obj), function (key) {
      return _.map(paths(obj[key], key), function (subkey) {
        return (parentKey ? parentKey + '.' : '') + subkey;
      });
    });
  }
  else {
    result = [];
  }
  return _.concat(result, parentKey || []);
}
```

Edit: If you truly want just the leaves, just return `result` in the last line.

Comment: Thanks @Nick Broderic. Do you think it would possible to remove recursion from your code and use _.flatMapDeep instead of that.

Comment: I do not believe that will work. The "Deep" part of "flatMapDeep" refers to the flatten operation, not the map operation. To see this, try running `(function () {  var _ = require('lodash'); console.log(_.flatMapDeep({a: {b: 1}}, function(v, k) { return k; }))})();`. This will print `[ 'a' ]` rather than `[ 'a', 'b' ]`.

Comment: changing last line to just return `result` gives empty array in the result.

Comment: @StanislauListratsenka Ah, true. I think what works instead is to return directly from the array and object branches, and `return [parentKey]` in the default `else`.

Answer (score 6):

Doesn't use lodash, but here it is with recursion:

```
var getLeaves = function(tree) {
    var leaves = [];
    var walk = function(obj,path){
        path = path || "";
        for(var n in obj){
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
                if(typeof obj[n] === "object" || obj[n] instanceof Array) {
                    walk(obj[n],path + "." + n);
                } else {
                    leaves.push(path + "." + n);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    walk(tree,"tree");
    return leaves;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on Nick answer, here is a TS / ES6 imports version of the same code

```
import {isArray,flatMap,map,keys,isPlainObject,concat} from "lodash";

// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36490174/82609
export function paths(obj: any, parentKey?: string): string[] {
  var result: string[];
  if (isArray(obj)) {
    var idx = 0;
    result = flatMap(obj, function(obj: any) {
      return paths(obj, (parentKey || '') + '[' + idx++ + ']');
    });
  } else if (isPlainObject(obj)) {
    result = flatMap(keys(obj), function(key) {
      return map(paths(obj[key], key), function(subkey) {
        return (parentKey ? parentKey + '.' : '') + subkey;
      });
    });
  } else {
    result = [];
  }
  return concat(result, parentKey || []);
}
```

Comment: love how the code in this answer has a link to this very answer, gives context and clarity

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. I only did it because I felt the other solutions used too much logic. Mine does not use lodash since I don't think it would add any value. It also doesn't make array keys look like `[0]`.

```
const getAllPaths = (() => {
    function iterate(path,current,[key,value]){
        const currentPath = [...path,key];
        if(typeof value === 'object' && value != null){
            return [
                ...current,
                ...iterateObject(value,currentPath) 
            ];
        }
        else {
            return [
                ...current,
                currentPath.join('.')
            ];
        }
    }

    function iterateObject(obj,path = []){
        return Object.entries(obj).reduce(
            iterate.bind(null,path),
            []
        );
    }

    return iterateObject;
})();
```

If you need one where the keys are indexed using `[]` then use this:

```
    const getAllPaths = (() => {
        function iterate(path,isArray,current,[key,value]){
            const currentPath = [...path];
            if(isArray){
                currentPath.push(`${currentPath.pop()}[${key}]`);
            }
            else {
                currentPath.push(key);
            }
            if(typeof value === 'object' && value != null){
                return [
                    ...current,
                    ...iterateObject(value,currentPath) 
                ];
            }
            else {
                return [
                    ...current,
                    currentPath.join('.')
                ];
            }
        }

        function iterateObject(obj,path = []){
            return Object.entries(obj).reduce(
                iterate.bind(null,path,Array.isArray(obj)),
                []
            );
        }

        return iterateObject;
    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Feeding that object through this function should do it I think.

```
recursePaths: function(obj){
var result = [];
//get keys for both arrays and objects
var keys = _.map(obj, function(value, index, collection){
    return index;
});


//Iterate over keys
for (var key in keys) {
    //Get paths for sub objects
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
        var paths = allPaths(obj[key]);
        for (var path in paths){
            result.push(key + "." + path);
        }
    } else {
        result.push(key);
    }
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work - for the OPs example object above I get [ '0', '1', '2' ]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function. It generates all possible paths with dot notation, assuming there are no property names containing spaces

```
function getAllPathes(dataObj) {
    const reducer = (aggregator, val, key) => {
        let paths = [key];
        if(_.isObject(val)) {
            paths = _.reduce(val, reducer, []);
            paths = _.map(paths, path => key + '.' + path);
        }
        aggregator.push(...paths);
        return aggregator;
    };
    const arrayIndexRegEx = /\.(\d+)/gi;
    let paths = _.reduce(dataObj, reducer, []);
    paths = _.map(paths, path => path.replace(arrayIndexRegEx, '[$1]'));

    return paths;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const allEntries = (o, prefix = '', out = []) => {
        if (_.isObject(o) || _.isArray(o)) Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => allEntries(v, prefix === '' ? k : `${prefix}.${k}`, out));
        else out.push([prefix, o]);
        return out;
    };
```

Array are returned as .0 or .1 that are compatible with _.get of lodash

Answer (score -1):

```
const getAllPaths = (obj: object) => {
  function rKeys(o: object, path?: string) {
    if (typeof o !== "object") return path;
    return Object.keys(o).map((key) =>
      rKeys(o[key], path ? [path, key].join(".") : key)
    );
  }

  return rKeys(obj).toString().split(",").filter(Boolean) as string[];
};
```

```js
const getAllPaths = (obj) => {
  function rKeys(o, path) {
    if (typeof o !== "object") return path;
    return Object.keys(o).map((key) =>
      rKeys(o[key], path ? [path, key].join(".") : key)
    );
  }

  return rKeys(obj).toString().split(",").filter(Boolean);
};

const test = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 1
    },
    d: 2
  },
  e: 1
}

console.log(getAllPaths(test))
```