# Get array of all Lodash paths of object

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I'm trying to figure out if there is a simple way to get a list of all the "paths" (as defined by Lodash) of an object.

That is:

```
getPaths({ a: 3, b: { c: 4, d: 0 }})

=> 
[
  ['a'],
  ['b', 'c'],
  ['b', 'd']
]
```

Is there such a mechanism in Lodash? Or a simple way to create one?

Comment: No direct way, AFAIK. You need to recursively traverse the object, and create the paths on your own, which, not necessarily requires lodash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128171/list-all-possible-paths-using-lodash

Comment: You can use [flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat) package for this.
Example: `Object.keys(flat(/* obj */))`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an out of the box method, but you can use `_.transform()` recursively to get the paths:

```js
const getPaths = o =>
  _.transform(o, (acc, v, k) => {

    const keys = _.isObject(v) && !_.isEmpty(v) ? 
      _.map(getPaths(v), sk => _.concat(k, ...sk))
      :
      [[k]];
  
    acc.push(...keys);
  }, []);


const result = getPaths({ a: 3, b: { c: 4, d: 0 }, e: {}, f: [{ g: {h: 5}}] });

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive approach as follows.

```js
const getPaths = (obj, arr = [], res = []) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value) getPaths(value, [...arr, key], res)
    else res.push([...arr, key])
  });
  return res;
}


console.log(getPaths({ a: 3, b: { c: 4, d: 0 }}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the pathes without storing the visited path to the actual object by reducing the given nested path or taking an empty placeholder `[[]]` for reducing just the actual key.

```js
function getPaths(object) {
    return object && typeof object === 'object' && Object.keys(object).reduce((p, k) => 
        (getPaths(object[k]) || [[]]).reduce((r, a) =>
            [...r, [k, ...a]], p), []);
}

console.log(getPaths({ a: 3, b: { c: 4, d: 0 } }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive function:

```js
function getPaths(obj, prefix) {
  let result = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    if (typeof obj[key] == "object" && obj[key] != null) {
      return getPaths(obj[key], key);
    } else {
      return prefix ? [prefix, key] : key;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(getPaths({ a: 3, b: { c: 4, d: 0 }}));
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the `&& obj[key] != null` for? Is there some situation where `obj[key]` can evaluate to `null` and also be `typeof` `object`?

Comment: Also, this produces a nested structure, not the flat array of arrays I'm looking for.

Comment: Because `typeof null == "object"`.

Comment: Huh, weird. Also I must have been tired, I'm sure I checked that, heh.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if there isn't an included method, here is my answer:

```js
function getPaths(obj, prefix = []) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((arr, key) => {
    const path = [...prefix, key];
    const content = typeof obj[key] === 'object' ? getPaths(obj[key], path) : [path];
    return [...arr, ...content];
  }, []);
}
       
console.log(getPaths({ a: 3, b: { c: 4, d: 0, e: { f: 9} }}));
;
```