# How to convert JSON to seperated item names

Tags: javascript, node.js

How could i convert a json object from

```js
{
  'data': {
    'x': {
      'y': 1
    }
  }
}
```

to

```js
{
  'data': { 'x': { 'y': 1 } },
  'data.x': { 'y': 1 },
  'data.y': { 1 }
}
```

help is really needed :D

Comment: Your result output isn't even a valid object.

Comment: Yes it is? what do you mean

Comment: They mean that it is indeed an invalid object

Comment: @Niiko no this part `{ 1 }` isn't

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List all possible paths using lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128171/list-all-possible-paths-using-lodash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the bad way to handle json.
I suggest a function `get` In [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get);

You can try

```js
const ob = {
  'data': {
    'x': {
      'y': 1
    }
  }
}
_.get(ob, 'data')
_.get(ob, 'data.x')
_.get(ob, 'data.x.y')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean

```
{
  'data': { 'x': { 'y': 1 } },
  'data.x': { 'y': 1 },
  'data.x.y': 1
}
```

You can do it with recursion:

```js
const foo = {
  'data': {
    'x': {
      'y': 1
    }
  }
};


const loop = (obj, path, result) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    result[`${path ? path + '.' : ''}${key}`] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));
    if(typeof value === 'object') {
      loop(value, `${path ? path + '.' : ''}${key}`, result); 
    }
  });
  return result;
}

const result = loop(foo, '', {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Was what i was looking for at the start but found out that lodash works way better, thanks anyways!