# Delete unused key:value properties in JSON file

Tags: json, bash

I have key:value JSON object that is used in my JavaScript project. Value is a string and this object looks like this

```
{
  key1:{
    someKey: "Some text",
    someKey2: "Some text2"
  },
  key2:{
    someKey3:{
      someKey4: "Some text3",
      someKey5: "Some text4"
    }
  }
}
```

I use it in the project like this: key1.someKey and key2.someKey3.someKey4. Do you have idea how to delete unused properties? Let's say we don't use key2.someKey3.someKey5 in any file in a project, so i want it to be deleted from a JSON file. To people in the comments. I did't say i want to use JavaScript for this. I don't want to use it in browser or server. I just want the script that can do that on my local computer.

Comment: Well, if that JSON lives on a server, that cannot happen from JavaScript ...  Otherwise hackers could write JS in the console and change your JSON couldn't they?  You are going to need a scripting language to do this on the server side .. I recommend using `bash` and `jq` for this.

Comment: @Zak — There are numerous server-side JS runtimes (including Node.js, Deno, Bun, Rhino, and Classic ASP). The OP didn't even say if they were writing a client-server app.

Comment: I wanted to run script locally to modify this JSON but i dont really know where to start.
The idea is that i get all the chained keys: key2.someKey3.someKey4 search for such in a project if its not found then delete someKey4 key:value pair in key2.someKey3.

Comment: @Quentin fair enough .. But as his comment above states "locally" --  My *assumption* that he meant "local JS" stands.  This cannot be done.  (Assuming "local" means "client end" .. If he means local as in "localhost" then you are correct.)

Comment: @Zak — I run plenty of local applications written using Node.js.

Comment: @celebert1 — Start by working out how you are going to run the JS in the first place. e.g. with Node.js. Then work out how to read files. Then how to manipulate objects in JS. Then how to write files. (Your question, as it stands, is too broad).

Comment: Sorry maybe i wasn't clear enough. I just want to delete property that is not used in my project. I just said its a JavaScript project, i didn't say i want to use javascript or any specific language, i just want to delete these key:value pairs (in JSON object) that are not used in my project in any js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you live within javascript and node, you can use something like this to get all the paths:

Using some modified code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70763473/999943

```
var lodash=require('lodash')  // use this if calling from the node REPL
// import lodash from 'lodash';  // use this if calling from a script
const allPaths = (o, prefix = '', out = []) => {
        if (lodash.isObject(o) || lodash.isArray(o)) Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => allPaths(v, prefix === '' ? k : `${prefix}.${k}`, out));
        else out.push(prefix);
        return out;
    };
let j = {
  key1: { someKey: 'Some text', someKey2: 'Some text2' },
  key2: { someKey3: { someKey4: 'Some text3', someKey5: 'Some text4' } }
}
allPaths(j)
[
  'key1.someKey',
  'key1.someKey2',
  'key2.someKey3.someKey4',
  'key2.someKey3.someKey5'
]
```

That's all well and good, but now you want to take that list and look through your codebase for usage.

The main choices available are text searching with `grep` or `awk` or `ag`, or parse the language and look through the symbolic representation of the language after it's loaded into your project.  Tree-shaking can do this for libraries... I haven't looked into how to do tree-shaking for dictionary keys, or some other `undefined` reference check like a linter may do for a language.

Then once you have all the instances found, then you either manually modify your list or use a json library to modify it.

My weapons of choice in this instance are:
`jq` and `bash` and `grep`

It's not infallible.  But it's a start.  (use with caution).

setup_test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkdir src
echo "key2.someKey3.someKey4" > src/a.js
echo "key1.someKey2" > src/b.js
echo "key3.otherKey" > src/c.js
```

test.json

```
{
  "key1":{
    "someKey": "Some text",
    "someKey2": "Some text2"
  },
  "key2":{
    "someKey3":{
      "someKey4": "Some text3",
      "someKey5": "Some text4"
    }
  }
}
```

check_for_dict_references.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

json_input=$1
code_path=$2

cat << HEREDOC
  json_input=$json_input
  code_path=$code_path
HEREDOC

echo "Paths found in json"
paths="$(cat "$json_input" | jq -r 'paths | join(".")')"

no_refs=
for path in $paths; do
  escaped_path=$(echo "$path" | sed -e "s|\.|\\\\.|g")
  if ! grep -r "$escaped_path" "$code_path" ; then
    no_refs="$no_refs $path"
  fi
done
echo "Missing paths..."
echo "$no_refs"

echo "Creating a new json file without the unused paths"
del_paths_list=
for path in $no_refs; do
  del_paths_list+=".$path, "
done
del_paths_list=${del_paths_list:0:-2} # remove trailing comma space

cat "$json_input" | jq -r 'del('$del_paths_list')' > ${json_input}.new.json
```

Running the `setup_test.sh`, then we can test the `jq` + `grep` solution

```
$ ./check_for_dict_references.sh test.json src
  json_input=test.json
  code_path=src
Paths found in json
src/b.js:key1.someKey2
src/b.js:key1.someKey2
src/b.js:key1.someKey2
src/a.js:key2.someKey3.someKey4
src/a.js:key2.someKey3.someKey4
src/a.js:key2.someKey3.someKey4
Missing paths...
 key2.someKey3.someKey5
Creating a new json file without the unused paths
```

If you look closely you would want it to also print `key1.someKey`, but this got "found" in the middle of the name `key1.someKey2`.  There are some more fancy regex things you can do, but for the purpose of this script it may be enough.

Now look in your directory for the new json file:

```
$ cat test.json.new.json
{
  "key1": {
    "someKey": "Some text",
    "someKey2": "Some text2"
  },
  "key2": {
    "someKey3": {
      "someKey4": "Some text3"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: it worked as expected, thanks you very much. Cant tell if its accuracy is 100% but its definetly works.